# What's wrong with the animation for the menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio, web

Okay so basically I have to do an internet site for school with HTML but only javascript animation, all the code work proprely but when I want to transform the three lines I use for my hamburger menu into a cross with a javascript animation nothing is happening and I really don't know why.
If someone can help me I will be really greatful as always, thanks for reading.

```
     <!doctype html>

    <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>California Hotel</title>
    
    <style>
        * {
           margin: 0;
           padding: 0;
           }

        
        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }


        .container{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: grey;
        }
        .navbar{
            width: 300px;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: blanchedalmond;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            border-radius: 10% 0 0 5%;
        }

        .hamburger-menu{
            width: 35px;
            height: 30px;
            position: fixed;
            top: 50px;
            right: 50px;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-around;
        }
        .line{
            width: 100%;
            height: 3px;
            background-color: black;
            
            
           

        }

        .change .line-1{
          transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px,6px);

        }
        .change .line-2{
          opacity: 0;
        }

        .change .line-3{
          transform: rotate(45deg)  translate(-8px,-6px);;
        }


        .nav-list{
            text-align: right;
        }

        .nav-item{
            list-style: none;
            margin: 25px;

        }

        .nav-links{
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 20px;
            color: rgb(22, 73, 73);
            font-weight: 300;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            position: relative;
            padding: 3px 0;

        }
        .nav-links::before,
        .nav-links::after{
            content: "";
            width: 100%;
            height: 2px;
            background-color: orange;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            transform: scaleX(0);
            transition: transform 0.5s;
            
            

        }
        
        .nav-links::after{
            bottom: 0;
            transform-origin: right;
        }

        .nav-links::before{
            top: 0;
            transform-origin: left;
        }

        .nav-links:hover::before,
        .nav-links:hover::after{
            transform: scaleX(1);
        }
    

      </style>
</head>
<body> 


    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="hamburger-menu">
                <div class="line line-1"></div>
                <div class="line line-2"></div>
                <div class="line line-3"></div>
            </div>
            


            <ul class="nav-list">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-links">A PROPOS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-links">NOUS CONTACTER</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-links">NOS RESEAUX SOCIAUX</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>

           <script>
            const menuIcon  = document.querySelector(".hamburger-menu");
           const navbar = document.querySelector(".nabar");
            MenuIcon.addEventListener("click",() => {
          navbar.classList.toggle(".change")});
          </script>
    

         </body> 
      </html>
```

Comment: change .nabar to .navbar and const MenuIcon . Note the lowercase and uppercase letters in JavaScript

Comment: yep I do that but it dosen't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your correct code :
missing ; and remove . before class in javascript code. good luck.

```js
               const MenuIcon = document.querySelector(".hamburger-menu");
               const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
               MenuIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
                   navbar.classList.toggle("change");
               });
```

```css
      * {
               margin: 0;
               padding: 0;
           }


           body {
               font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
           }


           .container {
               width: 100%;
               height: 100vh;
               background-color: grey;
           }

           .navbar {
               width: 300px;
               height: 100%;
               background-color: blanchedalmond;
               position: fixed;
               top: 0;
               right: 0;
               display: flex;
               justify-content: center;
               align-items: center;
               border-radius: 10% 0 0 5%;
           }

           .hamburger-menu {
               width: 35px;
               height: 30px;
               position: fixed;
               top: 50px;
               right: 50px;
               cursor: pointer;
               display: flex;
               flex-direction: column;
               justify-content: space-around;
           }

           .line {
               width: 100%;
               height: 3px;
               background-color: black;




           }

           .change .line-1 {
               transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 6px);

           }

           .change .line-2 {
               opacity: 0;
           }

           .change .line-3 {
               transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -6px);
               ;
           }


           .nav-list {
               text-align: right;
           }

           .nav-item {
               list-style: none;
               margin: 25px;

           }

           .nav-links {
               text-decoration: none;
               font-size: 20px;
               color: rgb(22, 73, 73);
               font-weight: 300;
               letter-spacing: 1px;
               text-transform: uppercase;
               position: relative;
               padding: 3px 0;

           }

           .nav-links::before,
           .nav-links::after {
               content: "";
               width: 100%;
               height: 2px;
               background-color: orange;
               position: absolute;
               left: 0;
               transform: scaleX(0);
               transition: transform 0.5s;



           }

           .nav-links::after {
               bottom: 0;
               transform-origin: right;
           }

           .nav-links::before {
               top: 0;
               transform-origin: left;
           }

           .nav-links:hover::before,
           .nav-links:hover::after {
               transform: scaleX(1);
           }
```

```html
       <div class="container">
           <nav class="navbar">
               <div class="hamburger-menu">
                   <div class="line line-1"></div>
                   <div class="line line-2"></div>
                   <div class="line line-3"></div>
               </div>



               <ul class="nav-list">
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a href="#" class="nav-links">A PROPOS</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a href="#" class="nav-links">NOUS CONTACTER</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="nav-item">
                       <a href="#" class="nav-links">NOS RESEAUX SOCIAUX</a>
                   </li>
               </ul>
           </nav>
       </div>
```

Comment: ty really sometimes I make some mistakes like that and I can't fix them cuz I don't know were's the problem so I need help of ppls ty sir really